# Рандомные ответы по умолчанию и ответы, заданные с HashMap

Tags: java, случайные-числа, java-hashmap, генерация-случайных-данных, hashmap

При вводе слова, которое не хранится в `HashMap`, должен выводить ответ по умолчанию, но вместо этого выводит `null`.

```
//класс, генерирующий ответы по умолчанию и заданные
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
/**
 * The responder class represents a response generator object.
 * It is used to generate an automatic response to an input string.
 * 
 * @author     Michael Kölling and David J. Barnes
 * @version    0.1 (2016.02.29)
 */
public class Responder
{
    private Random random;
    private ArrayList <String> responses;
    private HashMap<String, String> answersMap;
    /**
     * Construct a Responder - nothing to do
     */

    public Responder()
    {
        random = new Random();
        responses = new ArrayList<>();
        answersMap = new HashMap<>();

       fillResponse();
       fillResponseMap();
    }

    /**
     * Generate a response.
     * @return   A string that should be displayed as the response
     */
    //public String generateResponse()
    //{
      // int index = random.nextInt(responses.size()); 
      // return responses.get(index);
    //}

    public String generateResponse(String word){
     String answer = answersMap.get(word);
     if (word != null){
        return answer;
        }else{
       int index = random.nextInt(responses.size()); 
       return responses.get(index);
        }

    }
    /**
     * The range of default responses when the programme does not know the answer.
     */
    public void fillResponse(){
      responses.add("Did you check the FAQ section on our website?");
      responses.add("Could you describe the problem more detailed, please?");

    }

    /**
     * The range of answers (values) and their keywords.
     */
    public void fillResponseMap(){
    answersMap.put("slow","Probably, our app is not compatible with the OS of your PC");

    answersMap.put("call","We understand your frustration. Unfortunately, \n" + 
    "the phone call assistance is not supported. However, you can provide the \n" + 
    " following information about your problem in the email.");

    answersMap.put("refund", "I am sorry to hear you are not happy with our app. \n" +
    "As we can not give you a refund (more details in terms and conditions), \n" +
    "I would glad to offer you an alternative. \n" + 
    "Please, send us an email with a refund object");

    }
}
```

Вызывается код другим классом методом `start()`

```
    public void start()
    {
        boolean finished = false;

        printWelcome();

        while(!finished) {
            String input = reader.getInput();

            if(input.startsWith("bye")) {
                finished = true;
            }
            else {

                String response = responder.generateResponse(input);
                System.out.println(response);
            }
        }

        printGoodbye();
    }
```

Comment: помарка: при вводе слова

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю Вам надо было написать:

```
if (answer != null){
```

Так как `word` в данном случае нет смысла проверять на `null`.

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!!